# How to use Laravel Storage::file();

Tags: php, laravel

I wanted to check the files inside my public path 'public/img/certs' but it returns an array. Im currently using laravel 5.5 and my first time using the 'Storage' file system.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $path = base_path() . '/public/img/certs';

    $files = Storage::files($path);

    dd($files);
    return view('dashboard.index');
}
```

Comment: want to check what?

Comment: files inside that directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code, [reference link](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/145/getting-all-the-files-recursively-from-a-directory)

```
$files = File::allFiles($directory);
foreach ($files as $file)
{
    echo (string)$file, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! also just added use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

Answer (score 0):

First, `$files = Storage::files('$path');` won't work at all, because the variable won't be interpreted.

Second, `Storage::files` will return an array because you asked for file**s** and gave it a directory. The array will contain all the files in that directory.

Third, consider the `public_path` helper for this:

```
$path = public_path('img/certs');
```

It's a bit cleaner and will work if you ever put your public files somewhere non-standard.

Comment: thanks for answering, i tried cleaning it up and copied ur solution. It still returns an empty array.

Comment: Then there are no files in that directory, or Laravel doesn't have access to see the ones you want.

Comment: I tried just using the public_path('img'); but still returns an empty array even though there are images in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code in your controller hope this will help you to store the file in storage location of your application.

```
if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $image_name=$request->image->getClientOriginalName();
            $request->image->storeAs('public',$image_name); 
        }
        $request->user()->profile_pic=$request->image;
        $request->user()->save();
        return back();
```

Modified it according to your requirement so this code work definately.